# Is there any way to output saved rspec output file in color?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

If I were to run "rspec spec/" and save the resulting output to a file named "spec_output.txt". Is there a way to have "spec_output.txt" displayed in the terminal in color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is "no". There seem to be no color codes left in the file.

I've tried:

```
$ rspec spec/controllers/users_controller_spec -c -o out.txt
$ rspec spec/controllers/users_controller_spec -c > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to view it later (as opposed to process it somehow), you could always use the HTML output option, which has nice formatting in addition to color.

Answer (score 0):

In RSpec 3.9 you can use `--tty` flag to capture color codes.

```sh
$ bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/users_controller_spec --color --tty > ./tmp/rspec_results.txt

$ file ./tmp/rspec_results.txt
./tmp/rspec_results.txt: ASCII text, with escape sequences
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rspec 3.12 and this works:

```
rspec --force-color spec/path/to/example_spec.rb > colorful.txt
```